# Setting default value using data from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

When creating a table in SQLite, I want to define the default value of a column using value from another table (as this column is a foreign key). Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_1(A1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, B1 TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Test_2(A2 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, B2 INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT [a value in column A1 of Test_1]);
```

I assume that `Test_1` is already populated with the records that provides possible values for `B2` in `Test_2` table. For example, these may be some constants like 'Created', 'In Progress', 'Paused', 'Finished' for a 'Status' column (i.e. `B2`).

I can of course pick the primary key of a value from `Test_1` and hard code it as the default value for `B2`, but that is error prone if I change the data of `Test_1` later. At the same time, we cannot use `SELECT` statement inside a `CREATE`.

If this is not feasible in SQLite, is it possible for other SQL engines? Or more generally, is this something that should be enforced by application logic rather than by database design?

Comment: I think you have a confused expectation about foreign keys. When you insert a record to Test_1 a new record in Test_2 IS NOT automatically created. You can insert a few records into Test_1. When it is time to insert records into Test_2 what value to you want to select from A1? Foreign key does not mean one-to-one relationship

Comment: @cha, thanks for the comment. I assume that the records in `Test_1` are already there, e.g. they may be some constants for a certain column/field in `Test_2`. I merely want to use one of the constants defined in `Test_1` as the default value for the corresponding column in `Test_2` table.

Comment: @cha, please see edit above, where I give an example to clarify the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a [TRIGGER](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

You can test for the value of `B2` on INSERT and if it is not populated then you can select a value in column `A1` of `Test_1` and populate the column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Test_2_B2_value
AFTER INSERT ON Test_2
FOR EACH ROW WHEN Test_2.B2 IS NULL
BEGIN 
NEW.B2 = (SELECT A1 FROM Test_1 LIMIT 1);
END
```

Comment: How is the performance of triggers? Does using it impact the performance of database in any way?

Comment: I think if you don't overdo with them they should be fine. In sqlite triggers are especially fast as the only statement that is allowed there is one of update/insert/delete/select. You can't really put a lot of code there. So, you will not be able to slow down your system significantly